# Updating WordPress plugins asks for FTP credentials with GAE 1.9.18 SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, wordpress

I'm trying to update WordPress plugins running on my local GAE server but I am getting prompted to enter FTP credentials. The only thing I have changed is upgrading from AppEngine 1.9.17 SDK to 1.9.18. Does anyone know how to resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the issue in the App Engine issue queue and got an answer: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11753

The GAE 1.9.18 SDK made local filesystem read-only by default, I had to add this line to php.ini to resolve the issue:

```
google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem = 1
```

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't work for me. Any new updates on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change permissions using shh client such as Putty, Zoc etc...
and then type:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/folder-name/
after that it shouldn't ask you for ftp credentials.

Comment: Thanks but I am running this locally with the Google AppEngine SDK, there is no FTP access. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Answer (score 0):

WordPress asks for your FTP credentials when permissions aren't set correctly for WordPress to write files and folders. This can be caused by PHP running as the apache user (mod_php or CGI) rather than the user that owns your WordPress files. Upgrading may have changed the permissions of wp-content. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

A workaround is to put your FTP credentials directly in wp-config.php. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21' );
```

Comment: Thanks but I am running this locally with the Google AppEngine SDK, there is no FTP access. cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: OK, but somehow the permissions changed; that's why WP is complaining and asking for FTP credentials.